# Why are submissions to my mongo database blank?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, forms, mongoose

My form is successfully posting to a database hosted on mLab, but the only thing that comes through is an id number and ` "__v": 0'. I have five input fields labeled with names that correspond to my schema. Any ideas?

Here's my form:

```
<form action="/events" method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <legend>New Event</legend>

    <div class="form-1">
        <div>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Whale Watching">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="7/13">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="date">Time</label>
            <input type="text" id="time" name="time" placeholder="9:00am">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="ex. $150">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="capacity">Capacity</label>
            <input type="text" id="capacity" name="capacity" placeholder="ex. 12">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Create Event</button>

</fieldset>
```

my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const EventSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  time: Number,
  date: Date,
  price: Number,
  capacity: Number,
});

const Event = mongoose.model('events', EventSchema);

module.exports = Event;
```

My POST route:

```
router.post('/events', (req, res) => {
    Event.create(req.body).then(function(events){
        res.send(events);
    });
});
```

My server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./src/routes/index');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(routes);


mongoose.connect('mongodb://junk:junk@ds141242.mlab.com:41242/alaska-events');


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  });
```

Comment: Please edit to show your content insert code, and follow-on query. also: Have you done a direct native mongodb `find()` to see what's actually stored?

Comment: I'm probably in trouble, because I'm not sure what you mean by those first two. `Find` is contained in my `get` path like so:

`router.get('/', function(req, res){
   Event.find({}).then(function(events){
       res.render('index');
   });
 });`

Comment: Could you add the portion of your code that receives the POST and inserts data into the database?

Comment: Added the POST route!

Comment: also post the code where you spin up the express server and register middleware.

Comment: Added the server file.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by a friend. I'm submitting old fashioned form data but had not included

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`